# ntpd sporadic fail

Tags: internet, raspberrypi

I'm running Ubuntu 20.4 on Raspberry Pi 4 8GB. In a seemingly random pattern, the pi will lose connection to the internet and the date revert to Jan 10 after a time of ntpd being unable to sync. It won't recover without a reboot.

For a long time I thought this was due to a failure of the internet connection or dns and have been focussing on the router. But a similarly configured pi on the same network does not experience network loss.

When I look at the logs, it seems that ntpd itself is deleting the eth0 interface. I'm also seeing an apparmor="DENIED" message.  Am I right that ntpd itself is taking down the connection, and why the heck would it do that?

```
Mar 29 09:40:28 GethSync ntpd[21819]: Deleting interface #3 eth0, 192.168.178.62#123, interface stats: received=1690, sent=2151, dropped=0, active_time=354539 secs
Mar 29 09:40:28 GethSync ntpd[21819]: 91.189.91.157 local addr 192.168.178.62 -> 
Mar 29 09:40:28 GethSync ntpd[21819]: 194.104.0.153 local addr 192.168.178.62 -> 
Mar 29 09:40:28 GethSync ntpd[21819]: 46.249.42.13 local addr 192.168.178.62 -> 
Mar 29 09:40:28 GethSync ntpd[21819]: 84.245.9.254 local addr 192.168.178.62 -> 
Mar 29 09:40:28 GethSync ntpd[21819]: 213.154.236.182 local addr 192.168.178.62 -> 
Jan 10 05:56:46 GethSync kernel: [   10.479053] audit: type=1400 audit(1641790601.267:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ntpd" pid=712 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan 10 05:56:46 GethSync kernel: [   16.174144] audit: type=1400 audit(1641790606.963:33): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/snap/bin/" pid=837 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jan 10 05:56:46 GethSync ntpd[837]: ntpd 4.2.8p12@1.3728-o (1): Starting
Jan 10 05:56:46 GethSync ntpd[837]: Command line: /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 113:120
Jan 10 05:56:46 GethSync ntpd[880]: proto: precision = 0.148 usec (-23)
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync ntpd[880]: leapsecond file ('/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list'): good hash signature
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync ntpd[880]: leapsecond file ('/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list'): loaded, expire=2022-12-28T00:00:00Z last=2017-01-01T00:00:00Z ofs=37
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync ntpd[880]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync ntpd[880]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync ntpd[880]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync ntpd[880]: Listen normally on 3 lo [::1]:123
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync ntpd[880]: Listening on routing socket on fd #20 for interface updates
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync ntpd[880]: kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync ntpd[880]: kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync ntpd[880]: error resolving pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Jan 10 05:56:49 GethSync ntpd[880]: Soliciting pool server 197.82.150.123
Jan 10 05:56:50 GethSync ntpd[880]: Soliciting pool server 185.177.151.86
Jan 10 05:56:51 GethSync ntpd[880]: Soliciting pool server 94.198.159.15
Jan 10 05:56:52 GethSync ntpd[880]: Soliciting pool server 91.189.91.157
Jan 10 05:56:52 GethSync ntpd[880]: Listen normally on 4 eth0 192.168.178.62:123
Jan 10 05:56:52 GethSync ntpd[880]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 [fd00::1:dea6:32ff:feda:d36b]:123
Jan 10 05:56:52 GethSync ntpd[880]: Listen normally on 6 eth0 [fe80::dea6:32ff:feda:d36b%2]:123
Jan 10 05:56:52 GethSync ntpd[880]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
```

When I query the network log using `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` as suggested by waltinator, I see a number of warnings:

```
settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.4091] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.4107] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.4549] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.4736] device (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.4759] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.4933] device (wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.5670] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.6122] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.6124] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.6702] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.7475] sup-iface[0xaaaaf23a5910,wlan0]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.7512] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.7516] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlan0 created
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.7526] manager: (p2p-dev-wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Jan 10 05:56:47 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790607.7537] device (wlan0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 10 05:56:48 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790608.1511] device (eth0): carrier: link connected
Jan 10 05:56:50 GethSync.local NetworkManager[791]:   [1641790610.5715] manager: startup complete
```

Comment: Look at the network logs: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: Thanks, @waltinator I see several warnings and one Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate